# Get site url on mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to write a little helper function that returns the site url.
Coming from PHP and Codeigniter, I'm very upset that I can't get it to work the way I want.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
@{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var baseurl = urlHelper.Content("~");
}

<script>
    function base_url(url) {

        url = url || "";
        return '@baseurl' + url;
    }
</script>
```

I want to return the base url of my application, so I can make ajax calls without worrying about paths. Here's how I intend to use it:

```
// Development
base_url(); // http://localhost:50024

// Production
base_url("Custom/Path"); // http://site.com/Custom/Path
```

How can I do something like that?

**EDIT**

I want absolute paths because I have abstracted js objects that makes my ajax calls.
So suppose I have:

```
function MyController() {
   // ... js code
   return $resource('../MyController/:id');
}

// then
var my_ctrl = MyController();
my_ctrl.id = 1;
my_ctrl.get(); // GET: ../MyController/1
```

This works when my route is `http://localhost:8080/MyController/Edit` but will fail when is `http://localhost:8080/MyController` .

Comment: Why do you need the baseurl, if you can make ajax calls with a relative path?

Comment: RequestContext.Url will give you the Url of the request which is of type Uri (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx). RequestContext.Url.Host is the domain name.  But I have to agree with @Erwin, why do you want to use absolute URLs?

Comment: @Serg Ok. I'll do that next time

Comment: Thank you! I'll try all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
@{
    var url = Request.Url;
    var baseurl = url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: That is a bad way to do it. As others have said use the Url.Action or Url.RouteUrl. If you want an absolute URL then just use the overload of either of the mentioned methods which allows you to specify the scheme - i.e. http or https.

Comment: I think you missed the point. I can't use Url.Action or Url.RouteUrl since I'm doing it with Javascript.

Comment: When you render the view simply render the URL into some JS. e.g. in View:  <script>var someUrl = @Url.Action(...);</script>

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of `@Url.Action("actionname")` and `@Url.RouteUrl("routename")` ?

Both of these should do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *manually* creating your URL's, you can use `@Url.Action()` to construct your URLs.

```
<p>@Url.Action("Index", "Home")</p>
/Home/Index

<p>@Url.Action("Edit", "Person", new { id = 1 })</p>
/Person/Edit/1

<p>@Url.Action("Search", "Book", new { title = "Gone With The Wind" })</p>
/Book/Search?title="Gone+With+The+Wind"
```

Now the absolute best reason to go with this option is that `@Url.Action` automatically applies any vanity URL routes you have defined in your Global.asax file. DRY as the sub-saharan desert! :)

---

In your case, your can create a 'custom path' in two ways.

Option A)

```
<p>@Url.Action("Path", "Custom")</p>
/Custom/Path
```

Option B)

You can [create a route](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) using the Global.asax file. So your controller/action combo can be anything you want, and you can create a custom vanity route url - regardless of the controller/action combo.